# react native navigation bug

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

A-Stack: Z-Screen, X-Screen
B-Stack: Y-Screen

my flow :

1. Z-Screen navigate to Y-Screen
2. Y-Screen navigate to X-Screen

but when I navigate to X-Screnn from Y-Screen, Z-Screen mounted again between Y, X.

How can I solve this problem?

```
1. First Navigation - It's from ProgramTemplateDashboardListScreen
          navigation.navigate('ProductStack', {
            screen: 'ProductDetailScreen',
            params: {
              productId: programId,
              productType: 'PROGRAM',
            },
          });
2. Second Navigation
    navigation.navigate('ProgramTemplateStack', {
      screen: 'ProgramTemplateDetailProgramCompositionScreen',
      params: {
        programTemplateId: subprogramId,
      },
    });
```

Help me please..

Comment: you want to remount useEffect on back or something ?

Comment: No, I just want to navigate to Y from Z, X from Y. 
But when I navigate to X from Y, Z showed at the moment between Y, X.

If I use goBack() on X because I want go back to Y, But it's go back to Z.
something wrong..

Comment: are you using `navigation.push` somewhere ?

Comment: No, I used navigation.navigate only

Comment: There seems no problem in your route configurations. I would like to see where are you calling navigations and your useEffects of associated screens

Comment: Thank you guys, I solved this problem. I used navigation.replace. `navigation.replace('ProductStack', { screen: 'ProductDetailScreen', 
params: { productId: programId, productType: 'PROGRAM', }, }); ` 
using replace, I could not stack up previous Stack(A-Stack). So It doesn't showing again!